# Google analytics embed API: Line graph of single metric split by dimension

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, visualization

I am looking in to Google Analytics' Embed API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/), and it looks very useful, however, one thing I can't figure out how to do is create a Line Graph with multiple lines, one for each value of a dimension, on some metric.

For example I would like to graph sessions over time (ga:date for dimension, and ga:sessions as metric), but have a seperate line for each source (ga:source dimension). I could split and graph the data myself (either using google's visualization library, or a third party library), but this seems like a common use case, and I was surprised that I couldn't find an easy way to do it. Am I missing anything? Is there a way to generate this kind of line graph?

Comment: I think you will have to split the data yourself.  I tried to create the graph you described and couldn't do it with the Embed API.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I was just wondering if there was a better way to do it

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so. What are you using the Embed API for?